# How can I make concentric circles in HTML respond to mouseOver properly?

Tags: html, css

On my web page, I'd like to have a group of several concentric circles of varying size, with each displaying a menu when they are moused over.

So far, I have created 4 pictures that is 100% transparent except for the circle and have layered them on top of each other. However, when I mouse-over the group of circles, the transparent part of the top image causes the mouse-over event to fire. How can I deal with this?

For reference, here is the code that I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        img
        {
            position:fixed;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Circle Test</title>
</head>
<body>

        <img src="Circle2.png" onMouseover="alert('Button2')"/>
        <img src="Circle4.png" onMouseover="alert('Button4')"/>
        <img src="Circle3.png" onMouseover="alert('Button3')"/>
        <img src="Circle1.png" onMouseover="alert('Button1')"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be hard with pure images as it's difficult to tell when the mouse is actually over the circle part of the image. I would suggest a client side [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) as they let you define clickable areas in non-rectangular shapes. Set the href to something like "javascript:circleClicked(); void 0;" :D

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to tell that the mouse is over a transparent pixel of your circle: you must check if the mouse intersects with the actual circle (yeah, really). Actually, that's easier than it might seem. Considering your circle's diameter is your image's width (which appears quite possible to me), you just have to check that the mouse cursor is within the radius of the circle (which would be width / 2):

```
function intersectsCircle(diameter, center, mousePosition)
{
    var radius = diameter / 2;
    // compute the distance between mousePosition and center
    var deltaX = mousePosition.x - center.x;
    var deltaY = mousePosition.y - center.y;
    return Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY) < radius;
}
```

And the you just have to pass the required informations (my Javascript's rusty so what follows might not be exactly accurate, especially double-check the events part):

```
function intersects(target, event)
{
    var center = {x: target.x + target.width / 2, y: target.y + target.height / 2};
    var mousePosition = {x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY};
    if(intersectsCircle(target.width, center, mousePosition))
        alert('Foo');
}

<img onmouseover="intersects(this, event)" src="circle.png" />
```